# How find a general solution for this inhomogeneous $2^{nd}$-order DE: $y''-2y'+y=xe^{-x}\cos(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let the non-homogeneous differential equation:

$$\boxed{y''-2y'+y=x \cdot e^{-x} \cdot \cos(x) } \tag{1}$$

Notice that the RHS is of the form: $ b(x)=x\cdot e^{sx} \cdot \cos(tx) $ where $s=-1, t=1$

---

**Theorem 1**

> Let $y_p(x)$ be a particular solution of the non-homogeneous D.E and $y_0(x)$ be the general solution of the associated homogeneous equation (*a.k.a complementary equation*) then the general solution of the non-homogeneous equation is:
> $$ y_{g}(x) = y_p(x) + c_1 \cdot y_0(x)$$

---

### Complementary D.E's partial solution

The complementary D.E is a *second order linear D.E*: $\boxed{y''-2y'+y=0 } \quad(2)$

It's characteristic equation is: $\lambda^2 - 2\lambda + 1 = 0 $ Notice that $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=0$ therefore $\lambda= \frac{-b}{2a} = 1$

Hence, the general solution of the complementary D.E is: $\boxed{y_0(x) = c_1e^x+c_2xe^x } $

---

### Homogeneous D.E's general solution

#### Method of undetermined coefficients

Theory suggests that

> An educated guess about the particular solution of $(1)$ would be a solution of a similar form.

- My textbook suggests to use $y_{sub}(x) = z(x)e^{(s-it)x}$ as a guess to solve a small alternation of $(1)$ that is $\boxed{y''-2y'+y=P(x)e^{(s-it)x} \quad(4)}$ (where of course $e^{ix} =\cos(x)+i \sin(x)$). It then states that $Im(y_p(x))$ or $Re(y_p(x))$ will be the partial solution for $(1)$.
- [Another resource](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/17%3A_Second-Order_Differential_Equations/17.2%3A_Nonhomogeneous_Linear_Equations) suggests that for this form of $b(x)=ae^{αx} \cos βx+be^{αx} \sin βx$ I use $ Ae^{αx} \cos βx+Be^{αx} \sin βx $ as a guess with a note that *"The guess must include both terms even if either  a=0  or  b=0"*.

Lets follow my textbook's advice:

$\text{Let}\quad \:\:\: y_{sub}(x) = z(x)\cdot e^{(-1+i)x} \\
\text{then} \quad \: y_{sub}^{(1)}(x) =(z'(x)-(1-i)z(x)) \cdot e^{(-1+i)x}  \\
\text{and} \quad \:\: y_{sub}^{(2)}(x) = (z''(x) - (2- 2i)z'(x) - 2iz(x))\cdot e^{(-1+i)x}$

Plugging the partial and its derivatives in $(4)$ we have:

$y''-2y'+y=x \cdot e^{(-1+i)x} \iff \\ $
$(z'' - (2- 2i)z' - 2iz)\cdot e^{(-1+i)x} + (-2z'+2(1-i)z) \cdot e^{(-1+i)x} + z\cdot e^{(-1+i)x} =  x \cdot e^{(1-i)x} \iff\\$
$z'' - (2- 2i)z' - 2iz -2z' + 2(1-i)z + z = x \iff  $

$z''-4z'+2iz'-4iz+3z=x \iff \\$

$$ \boxed{z''+2z(-2+i)+z(3-4i) = x} \tag{5}$$

Now, $(5)$ has $b(x) = $ polynomial therefore a partial solution guess would be of the form

- $y_{sub_2} = ax+b \iff$
- $y^{(1)}_{sub_2} = a \iff$
- $y^{(2)}_{sub_2} = 0$

Hence plugging the partial solution and the derivatives in $(5)$ we have:

$z''+2z(-2+i)+z(3-4i) = x \iff$

$0 +2a(-2+i)+(ax+b)(3-4i) -x =0 \iff $

$ -4a +i2a +3ax -i4ax +3b -i4b -x =0 \iff $

$$ \boxed{[(3a-1)x - (4a +3b)] + i[4ax + (2a -4b) ] = 0} \quad (6)$$

Let's take the imaginary part of $(6)$ then:

$$ (E) =
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(3a-1)x - (4a +3b) = 0 \\
4ax + (2a -4b) = 0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

But there is no solution for this system... For example one the first equation $a = \frac13$ and on the second $a=0$ which is a contradiction. I triple checked the calculations (thus I reckon they are correct). I can't understand what went wrong. But most of all I can't really grasp the way of solving these inhomogeneous differential equations (that include a polynomial, an exponential and a trigonometric function). It all seems overly complicated to me.

I know this is a big post and not one, but several questions arise, so I for clarity purposes, I'll stick to the initial question: **How to solve this differential equation?**

*P.S: Of course any other answers are highly appreciated :)*

Cheers!

Comment: @Moo No. It is now, thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with Variation of Parameters? Undetermined Coefficients and Laplace Transforms should also work.

Comment: @Moo Wouldn't a Laplace transform require the knowledge of $y(0)$? Undetermined Coefficients is what I attempted here. Varation of parameters could indeed be a good idea, thanks.

Comment: No, you can just leave the ICs as is in the Laplace Transform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$y''-2y'+y=xe^{-x}\cos(x)$$
This differential equation is equivalent to:
$$(ye^{-x})''=xe^{-2x} \cos x$$
Integrate twice.

---

**Edit1:**
$$y''-2y'+y=xe^{-x}\cos(x)$$
Multiply by $e^{-x}$
$$e^{-x}(y''-2y'+y)=xe^{-2x}\cos(x)$$
$$e^{-x}(y''-y')-e^{-x}(y'-y)=xe^{-2x}\cos(x)$$
$$(e^{-x}y')'-(e^{-x}y)'=xe^{-2x}\cos(x)$$
$$(e^{-x}y'-e^{-x}y)'=xe^{-2x}\cos(x)$$
$$(e^{-x}y)''=xe^{-2x}\cos(x)$$

Comment: It is good to me

Comment: Thank you @Dinush

Comment: I don't understand this. Could you please expand a little more?  $(ye^{-x})''=xe^{-2x} \cos x \iff \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \:x^2}\left(ye^{-x}\right)=e^{-x}y =xe^{-2x} \cos x \iff e^{-x}y = xe^{-2x}  $. How is this equivalent to the differential equation I posted? On the other hand $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \:y^2}\left(ye^{-x}\right)=0$.

Comment: I hope it"s more clear @Dimitris

Comment: Indeed. That's great!

Comment: you're welcome @Dimitris

Answer (score 1):

I would try a particular solution of the form
$$
y_p(x)=e^{-x}[(ax+b)\cos x+(cx+d)\sin x]
$$

Answer (score 0):

### Variation of Parameters & the Wronskian

We know the general solution of the complementary $\boxed{y_0(x) = c_1e^x+c_2xe^x } \quad(1)$

**Theorem**

> Let the ODE $a_ny^{(n)} +a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)} + \cdots + a_1y' +a_0y =b$ and let $\{y_1,y_2\}$ be a fundamental set of solutions of the ODE. Then a **partial solution** of the ODE is:
> $$ y_p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{2}y_i(x)\int_{x_0}^{x} \frac{W_i(y_1,y_2)(t)}{W(y_1,y_2)(t)}\cdot \frac{b(t)}{a_n(t)} dt$$ where $W$ i the Wronskian determinant

Choose $x_0 =0$.

- $ W(y_1,y_2)(t)  = 
  \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
  y_1 & y_2  \\
  y^{'}_1  &  y^{'}_2   
   \end{array} \right| =
  \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
  e^t & te^t \\
  e^t &  e^t(1+t)
   \end{array} \right| = e^{2t}(1+t) - e^{2t}t = e^{2t}
  $
- $ W_1(y_1,y_2)  = 
  \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & te^t \\
  1 &  e^t(1+t)
   \end{array} \right| = -te^t
  $
- $ W_2(y_1,y_2)  = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
  e^t & 0 \\
  e^t &  1
   \end{array} \right| = e^t$

Furthermore $a_n(t) = 1$ and $b(t) = te^{-t}cos(t)$

Hence the partial solution is:

$$ y_p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{2}y_i(x)\int_{0}^{x} \frac{W_i(y_1,y_2)(t)}{W(y_1,y_2)(t)}\cdot \frac{b(t)}{a_n(t)} = \\
 e^x \int_{0}^{x} \frac{-te^t}{e^{2t}}\cdot te^{-t}cos(t) dt + xe^x \int_{0}^{x} \frac{e^t}{e^{2t}}\cdot te^{-t}cos(t) dt  (1) $$

Solving those on Wolfram Alpha [I1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20_0%5Ex%5C%3A%5Cfrac%7Bte%5Et%7D%7Be%5E%7B2t%7D%7D%5Ccdot%20%5C%3Ate%5E%7B-t%7Dcos%5Cleft%28t%5Cright%29%5C%3Adt%5C%3A), [I2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bx%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Be%5Et%7D%7Be%5E%7B2t%7D%7D%5Ccdot%20te%5E%7B-t%7Dcos%28t%29%20dt):

$y_p(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{125} (- 2 (10 x + 11) sin(x) + (15 x + 4) cos(x))$

---

**Note:** [This is the same result as the @Aryadeva's result who used another method on her/his answer.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cint%20%5Cint%20%5C%3Axe%5E%7B-2x%7D%5Ccos%20%5Cleft%28x%5Cright%29%7D%7Be%5E%7B-x%7D%7D)