# Differential equation solution using Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation
> $$y''+8y'+32y=8x^{3}e^{-4x}\sin(4x)$$
> Using the method of undetermined coefficients

What i tried:

The auxiliary equation corresponding to that equation is

$$r^2+8r+32=0\Longrightarrow r=\frac{-8\pm\sqrt{64-128}}{2}=\frac{-8\pm 8i}{2}=-4\pm 4i$$

So $$y_{c}=A_{1}e^{(-4+4i)x}+A_{2}e^{(-4-4i)x}=c_{1}e^{-4x}\cos(4x)+c_{2}e^{-4x}\sin(4x)$$

But i did not understand how to find a particular solution using method of Undetermined Coefficients.

Please Help me. Thanks

Comment: I've asked a similar question here, an inhomogeneous second order ODE of that exact form (exponential, trigonometric and polynomial on the RHS), it may help you as the methodology is the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796513/how-find-a-general-solution-for-this-inhomogeneous-2nd-order-de-y-2yy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting **P.I.**,

Just do , $$\frac{8\cdot e^{(4i-4)x}\cdot x^{3}}{D^{2}+8D+32} $$
$$=\frac{8\cdot e^{(4i-4)x}\cdot x^{3}}{(D+4)^{2}+16} $$
$$=8\cdot e^{(4i-4)x} \frac{x^{3}}{(D+4i-4+4)^{2}+16} $$
$$=8\cdot e^{(4i-4)x} \frac{x^{3}}{D^{2}+8Di} $$
$$=(-i)\cdot e^{(4i-4)x} (\frac{1}{D}-\frac{1}{8i}+\frac{D}{(8i)^{2}}-\frac{D^2}{(8i)^3}+\frac{D^3}{(8i)^4}-\frac{D^4}{(8i)^5}+\cdot\cdot\cdot)\cdot x^{3} $$
$$=(-i)\cdot e^{(4i-4)x} (\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^3}{8i}+\frac{3x^2}{(8i)^{2}}-\frac{6x}{(8i)^3}+\frac{6}{(8i)^4}) $$
I think , you would get it from here,,, for the **P.I.** , just take the imaginary part .

Answer (score 1):

Set
$$ y_p=(C_1x+C_2x^2+C_3x^3+C_4x^4)e^{-4x}\cos(4x)+(D_1x+D_2x^2+D_3x^3+D_4x^4)e^{-4x}\sin(4x). $$

Comment: You do not need $C_0$ and $D_0$, as they belong to the homogeneous solution, and thus cancel when inserting the trial solution.

Comment: You are right. Thanks